# I'm looking to run a video file on loop inside of a tkinter window with a bunch of other buttons, inputs, etc

Tags: python, tkinter

I've looked around on SO for ages and can't find what i'm looking for.

What I'm trying to do is get a program to run and look like this:

[Combined With the power of editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e66Gm.png)

With the video file embedded in tkinter window in column 0 under the title. However all I have been able to achieve so far is the video in a separate window to the rest of the GUI.

[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyfLk.png)

[Video File window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTYXG.png)

How do I embed this video into the GUI window on column 0?

This is the portion of the code I have been running to generate both windows so far

```
os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'root'
clip = VideoFileClip("Produce_3.avi")



clip.preview()
```

Your help is very much appreciated and thank you in advance!
-Anthony